# Why doesn't work my MySQL transaction from VB?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, transactions

Good morning,
I need a transaction cause if I had some issues I will like don't create nothing, scheme, table nothing.
But it writes on my db always, for example in my code I didnt put the name field in the Insert but it creates scheme and table so the 2 commands before.
Where I'm wrong?
Thank you

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MySql.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" %>

<%RunTransaction("server=localhost;user id=root;password=xxx$;Database=ooo")%>

<script runat="server">

Public Sub RunTransaction(myConnString As String)
Dim myConnection As New MySqlConnection(myConnString)
myConnection.Open()

Dim myCommand As MySqlCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand()
Dim myTrans As MySqlTransaction

myTrans = myConnection.BeginTransaction()
myCommand.Connection = myConnection
myCommand.Transaction = myTrans

Try
    myCommand.CommandText = "CREATE SCHEMA xxx DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_cs;" 
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE xxx.ITEMIMG (IDITE VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, IDIMG VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, IMG VARCHAR(255) NULL, COVER INT NULL, DATINS DATE NULL, PRIMARY KEY (IDITE, IDIMG))"
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO xxx.ITEMIMG (IDITE, , IMG, DATINS) VALUES ('maquillaje-1','maquillaje-1-img-1', '/maquillaje-1.jpg', NOW())"
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myTrans.Commit()

    response.write("Both records are written to database.")

Catch e As Exception

    myTrans.Rollback()
    response.write("rollaback")

Finally

    myConnection.Close()
    response.write("chidi connessione")

End Try
End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: DML statements (INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE) can be executed in context of transaction, can be committed and rolled back. But DDL statements cause an implicit commit, and cannot be rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

**DDL** statements cause an implicit commit; outside the control of a transaction.

Aside from SELECT, a SQL statement falls into one of two broad categories: **DML** (Data Manipulation Language) and **DDL** (Data Definition Language)

Think of **DML** statements as row-wise operations. `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements operate on rows. These operations can be executed within a transaction, and are subject to `ROLLBACK` and `COMMIT`.

Think of **DDL** statements as column-wise operations. `CREATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE`, statements create, modify or drop columns. (DDL statements operate on more than just tables and columns, but for the purposes of this discussion, we'll focus on column-wise operations vs row-wise operations. The DDL operations cause implicit commit, are not subject to transaction ROLLBACK.

This behavior is not unique to MySQL.

Note that the introduction of "atomic DDL" in MySQL 8.0 doesn't really change this. The CREATE TABLE statement either succeeds and is automatically committed, or it fails.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/atomic-ddl.html